# Oracle : count and group by request return no rows instead of 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that counts the number of `acc_ene` satisfying the condition `ene.ene_type = 'PRCECO'` and `deal.deal_scope = 'Y'`, for a given `run_id`

Here is the query :

```
select run.run_id, 35, count(*), sysdate
from dt_runs run
join acc_deals deal on deal.deal_cnt_id = run.deal_cnt_id
join acc_ene ene on ene.deal_id = deal.deal_id and ene.ene_cnt_id = run.ene_cnt_id
where ene.ene_type = 'PRCECO'
and deal.deal_scope = 'Y'
and run.run_id = '&1'
group by run.run_id, 35, sysdate;
```

However, when no such `acc_ene` exists, instead of returning `0`, the query returns no row.
Is there a way to modify my query to make it return `0` ?

I already tried with `nvl(count(*), 0)` (-> not better) and this query, which seemed to work:

```
select run.run_id, 34, (select count(*) from acc_ene ene where ene.ene_type = 'PRCECO'), sysdate
from dt_runs run, acc_deals deal, acc_ene ene 
where ene.deal_id = deal.deal_id
and ene.ene_cnt_id = run.ene_cnt_id
and deal.deal_scope = 'Y'
and run.run_id = '&1'
and deal.deal_cnt_id = run.deal_cnt_id 
group by run.run_id, 34, sysdate;
```

But then I tried with a different `ene.ene_type = 'IMM'`, for which I know there are records in the table. It returned the total number of `acc_ene` of type `'IMM'`, instead of the number of this type of `acc_ene` for a particular run.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there's no data ind you got a GROUP BY there's no result, this is just how SQL works.

Try to change it using Outer Joins instead:

```
select run.run_id, 35, count(ene.deal_id), sysdate
from dt_runs run
left join acc_deals deal 
  on deal.deal_cnt_id = run.deal_cnt_id
 and deal.deal_scope = 'Y'
left join acc_ene ene
  on ene.deal_id = deal.deal_id 
 and ene.ene_cnt_id = run.ene_cnt_id
 and ene.ene_type = 'PRCECO'
where run.run_id = '&1'
group by run.run_id, 35, sys date;
```

Or get rid of the GROUP BY, you just want data for a single run_id:

```
select min(run.run_id), 35, count(*), sysdate
from dt_runs run
join acc_deals deal on deal.deal_cnt_id = run.deal_cnt_id
join acc_ene ene on ene.deal_id = deal.deal_id and ene.ene_cnt_id = run.ene_cnt_id
where ene.ene_type = 'PRCECO'
and deal.deal_scope = 'Y'
and run.run_id = '&1';
```

I can't test if Oracle accepts constants without group by, otherwise you might have to use

```
select min(run.run_id), min(35), count(*), min(sys date)
```